# Maven plugin complex parameter initialization via system properties

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-plugin

I need to run maven plugin from console. In plugin i need a complex parameter kind of:

```
/**
* @goal do-automation
**/
public class AutomationMojo extends AbstractMojo {

/**
 * The current maven project.
 *
 * @parameter expression="${project}"
 */
protected MavenProject project;

/**
 * App configuration.
 *
 * @parameter expression="${appConfig}"
 */
private AppConfig appConfig;
```

AppConfig parameter looks smth like this:

```
public class AppConfig {

private String path

private String version

}
```

I will be running maven plugin in the following way:

mvn group:artifact:version:do-automation -Dproperty.for.appConfig

How can i set AppConfig properties via system properties? It is possible?

i tried the following and it didn't work for me:

```
public class AppConfig {
/**
* @parameter expression="${path}"
*/
private String path

private String version

}
```

mvn group:artifact:1.0-SNAPSHOT:do-automation -DappConfig.path=122 -Dpath=122
It created AppConfig with null values for properties

I am using:
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 14:46:01-0430)
Java version: 1.6.0_21
Java home: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7" version: "6.1" arch: "x86" Family: "windows"

Answer (score 4):

Actually Maven 3 provides some other means to do what you want. Please, have a look to this link, section (Bean Default Properties)

http://blog.sonatype.com/people/2011/03/configuring-plugin-goals-in-maven-3/

You can define set(String configStr) method in your AppConfig and parse string passed from command line. For Instance.

```
mvn group:artifact:1.0-SNAPSHOT:do-automation -DappConfig=my/path,version
```

Then you will be able to parse "my/path,version" in the set(...) method appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

you have read [this](http://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html) already. Here is an excerpt:

> configuration      @parameter expression="${aSystemProperty}"
>   default-value="${anExpression}"
>
> Specifies the expressions used to calculate the value to be injected
>   into this parameter of the Mojo at buildtime. The expression given by
>   default-value is commonly used to refer to specific elements in the
>   POM, such as ${project.resources}, which refers to the list of
>   resources meant to accompany the classes in the resulting JAR file. Of
>   course, the default value need not be an expression but can also be a
>   simple constant like true or 1.5. And for parameters of type String
>   one can mix expressions with literal values, e.g.
>   ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-special. The system property
>   given by expression enables users to override the default value from
>   the command line via -DaSystemProperty=value. NOTE: If neither
>   default-value nor expression are specified, the parameter can only be
>   configured from the POM. The use of '${' and '}' is required to
>   delimit actual expressions which may be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

you should change your configuration like the following:

```
/**
 * App configuration.
 *
 * @parameter
 */
private AppConfig appConfig;


public class AppConfig {
/**
* @parameter expression="${appConfig.path}"
*/
private String path

/**
* @parameter expression="${appConfig.version}*/
private String version

}
```

This should give the opportunity to use your system configuration arguments. First i would check if the configuration via usual configuration tag for a plugin works as expected to see if something different is wrong.

Comment: Have you checked via usual configuration in a pom not via parameters on command line?